# Can I verify the existence of Master Page from base page class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm improving my webforms by moving repeated or common code/functions to a base page class. But even if every webforms use the same functions, I need to manage some specific situation like the next code:

```
Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
.
.
.
  Private Sub Session()
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
  End Sub
.
.
End Class
```

If the code is executed in a web form with master page everything will go fine but if the code is inside a page without a master page and also inside an iframe, I fear that the redirection will work only inside the iframe.

Is it possible to detect if I have a Master page in order to manage those events?

**If the answer is written in c# I can try to translate the code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find your master page by using the Master Property:

```
'Declaration
<BrowsableAttribute(False)> _
Public ReadOnly Property Master As MasterPage
```

Taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master(v=vs.140).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).